# I'm trying to the create the most technologically advanced civilization possible

Tags: science-based, technology, technological-development, civilization

I'm trying to make a civilization that has achieved apotheosis in every field. Basically the very highest point of advancement in that area; it is one thing that is the final achievement. What is that one thing in all these fields based on the knowledge we have today? (I'm sure when we reach said thing, science will open up more)

1.) Chemistry

2.) Physics

3.) Mathematics

4.) Biology

5.) Computer science

6.) Medicine

7.) Engineering

8.) Philosophy

9.) Economics

10.) Psychology

11.) Geology (this may be pointless as "GEOLOGY IS NOT A REAL SCIENCE"- Sheldon Cooper)

12.) Agriculture

Comment: This is way too broad.  It may be impossible to answer for just one field... but a dozen?  Worse, you're asking about fields that don't actually have a limit.  Engineering?  Which branch?  I'm not sure that matters since engineers use what the hard sciences discover to build things.  Philosophy?  The nature of the field would be to dispute the proposed apotheosis.  What are you trying to do with this?

Comment: You would have a civilization of literal gods.

Comment: This seems like you've wandered into ontology where imagining an ultimate *whatever* will be bypassed something unimaginably better. You may need to rethink your question. Although the medical apotheosis could be practical immortality, Geology is real science, whether it can have an apotheosis that is another thing. As for Sheldon Cooper's comment on geology, he has rocks in his head.

Comment: No way to answer this in a sensible way. Science does not work that way. You can state what is, today, considered something achievable but beyond our reach, at least on some of those disciplines (e.g.: space elevator for Engineering). P.S.: We could debate if Philosophy or Engineering is "a real Science", but Geology surely *is*; it might not be an "exact science", but it follows scientific method strictly, so Science it is.

Comment: The question says that they have *"achieved apotheosis"*. Therefore they are gods; that's what _apotheosis_ means. You are asking mortals to describe the divinity in detail.

Answer (score 2):

0 - Ascension. Your advanced civilization has reached to a level that none of the sciences you mentioned has any need. They have ascended, exists as pure thought and have absolute control over the universe. They are basically gods. Look for Alterans in StarGate universe.